# Using $resource to upload file

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have gone through all the questions on this website on this topic and pretty much tried all codes. Following is the latest snippet that I have borrowed from the answers listed on this website. I am trying to upload a file asynchronously to AWS s3 endpoint. I get my signed url correctly but am unable to actually upload the file.

HTML:

```
<form name="Details" ng-controller="DetailsController">
 <input type="file" file-input="files" />
 <button ng-click="initUpload()">Upload</button>
</form>
```

fileInput Directive and DetailsController:

```
module.directive('fileInput', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link:function(scope, elm, attrs){
          elm.bind('change', function(){
            $parse(attrs.fileInput)
                .assign(scope, elm[0].files);
              scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    }
}]).controller("DetailsController", ["$scope", "PostalService",
  function ($scope, PostalService) {

      getSignedURLForUpload = function(userId, filename, filetype){
          return (PostalService.getSignedURLForUpload(userId, filename, filetype));

     };

    $scope.initUpload = function(){
        var signedUrl = getSignedURLForUpload($scope.userId, $scope.files[0].name,$scope.files[0].type);
        signedUrl.then(function (data) {
            var uploadPromise = PostalService.uploadFile($scope.files, data.signedRequest);
            uploadPromise.then(function(result) {
                $scope.awsurl =  data.url;
            });
        });

    };

]);
```

PostalService:

```
module.factory("PostalService",
  ["$resource",
  function($resource) {

    var functions = {
      getSignedURLForUpload: function(userId, filename, filetype) {
        var SignUrl = $resource("host end point?userid="+userId+"&file-name="+filename+"&file-type="+filetype);
        var promise = SignUrl.get().$promise;
        return promise;
      },

      uploadFile: function(file, signedRequest) {
        var Upload = $resource(signedRequest, null, {
          'save':{
            method: 'POST',
              transformRequest: function(data){
                var fd = new FormData();
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                  if(value instanceof FileList) {
                    if(value.length ===1){
                      fd.append(key, value[0]);
                    }else {
                      angular.forEach(value, function(file, index){
                        fd.append(key+'_'+index, file);
                      });
                    }
                  }else {
                    fd.append(key, value);
                  }
                });
                return fd;
              },
              headers: {'Content-Type' : undefined}
          }
        });

        var promise = Upload.save(file).$promise;
        return promise;
      }



    };
    return functions;
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in implementation of uploadFile function of PostalService.

The headers needed to be set properly:
1. 'Content-Type' : 'image/jpeg' 
2. Authorization: 'undefined'

Authorization headers were being automatically set by my application and in this case, I had to nullify them as the particular url link used to upload the file to the server was pre-signed and signature was part of the query.

Content type needed to be 'image/jpeg' and not undefined as that was expected by my backend server.

Finally, the method 'POST' didn't work. Had to replace it with 'PUT' instead.